# Custom compiler for XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

How to add LLVM 3.1 to XCode (version 4.5 with LLVM 4.2)? There's a flag (default com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0), but I've no idea how to use it...